# Am I achieving the singleton behavior I want using the concurrent dictionary?

Tags: c#, singleton, ref, concurrentdictionary

I have a dll which provides access to a certain device.  There can only be one instance of this dll per device. I will refer to this as the `Link` item / object.

below is my code which is used in an ASP.NET Web API. Multiple Web requests come in and then use the dll to issue commands to the device.

I have a static class which acts as my singleton provider for the link.

```
public static class LinkProviderAsync
    {
        //Dictionary that stores all the links
        private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, Link> DeviceLinks;      

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor
        /// </summary>
        static LinkProviderAsync()
        {
            int numProcs = Environment.ProcessorCount;
            int concurrencyLevel = numProcs * 2;
            DeviceLinks = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Link>(concurrencyLevel, 64);
            GC.KeepAlive(DeviceLinks);  <<-- me experimenting.          
        }     

        /// <summary>
        /// Call this to find your correct link for the device id
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="deviceId">The device Id</param>
        /// <param name="userId">The id of the user</param>
        /// <returns>A reference to a Link</returns>
        public static async Task<Link> GetDeviceLinkAsync(string deviceId, string userId)
        {
            Link link;
            if (!DeviceLinks.TryGetValue(deviceId, out link))
            {
                return await CreateNewLink(deviceId, userId);
            }
            //Already exists so just return the connection
            return link;
        }      

       ///
       // Creates a new instance of a Link if it does not already exist
       ///
       private static async Task<Link> CreateNewLink(string deviceId, string userId)
       {
          Link link = new Link(deviceId, userId);
          if (DeviceLinks.TryAdd(deviceId, link))
             {
                  return link;
             }
          return null;
       }
   }
```

Ok so let me explain what this class is SUPPOST to do. I is meant to keep a static list of all the currently active Links. There should only every be one of these lists in memory. There should also only ever be ONE of each instance in that list. Ie there can only be one `Link` for a `key` in the dictionary.

Now, how I use my `LinkProviderAsync` in an action method in my web ap controller.

```
public class DeviceConnectionController : ApiController
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Opens up a tcp connection to the specified device 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="model"></param>
        /// <returns> Returns 200 response status if it went ok</returns>
        ///         
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Open(DeviceConnectionOpenModel model)
        {
            var link = await LinkProviderAsync.GetDeviceLinkAsync(model.deviceId, User.Identity.GetUserId());

            try
            {
                await LinkCommandExecutorAsync.TryConnectLinkAsync(link);
                // Will be connected, if not an exception would be have been thrown.               
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
               ...
            }
         }
      }
```

This basically gets the specific link for the specified device id. It then passes it off to the `LinkCommandExecutorAsync` where I then call the specific functionality which the ddl provides.

I will post an example here as to not leave out any info:

```
    public static async Task TryConnectLinkAsync(Link link, string panelCode = null)
    {
        //Check that there is not someone else connected to the device already
        if (link.LinkConnectionStatus == ConnectionStatus.Connected )
        {
            return;
        }
        if (!await link.ConnectAsync(panelCode))
        {               
            //Connection or Network Error
            throw new ConnectionErrorException();
        }
        //Connection Successful if it reaches this point
    }
```

**My questions:**

1. Is the static class, constructor and static dictionary sufficient? Or would a singleton pattern be a better suited approach? I simply prefer the static class as its easily accessible everywhere in my code.
2. Am I really achieving a single instance of my 'Link' per device? Or do I actually need to make use of `ref` everywhere when I pass the link to and from methods?
3. Does the `TryGetValue()` method on the concurrent dictionary return a copy of the object or a reference to the object stored in the dictionary?

The `link` dll its self queues up commands. This is meant to be a thread safe implementation as multiple threads will be calling the same `LinkProviderAsync` class and often multiple threads issuing commands on the same instance of the `link`

Comment: Singleton is design pattern, implementing it with static class/static property is an option so not sure what your first question is.

Comment: You don't show any code that adds item to dictionary so it is not possible to say anything about correctness... The only guess could be based on completely random call to `GC.KeepAlive` which *may hint* on randomly jamming lines of code together - but I assume this is not the case...

Comment: The `GC.KeepAlive()` was just me experimenting with keeping the dictionary alive in the `iis` hosting environment. I didn't think the add was critical, but will add to the post now.

Comment: `TryGetValue()` returns an item based on a given key.  No "copy" will be made.

Comment: @JamesWilkins so it returns a reference to the item?

Comment: Yes, the same one it was set with for the given key.

Comment: Looks ok to me - there are more cases when you get null than you seem to expect (especially if `GetDeviceLinkAsync` actually does async work not shown in sample), but it does not impact correctness; there is also suspicious "userId" parameter (not used in sample) - if used to create "link" it will cause user credentials be cached/used by other users...

Comment: Care to elaborate on the cases where I can get null? the userId is actually used I just copied it incorrectly. The async work is hidden as is unrelated to my issue.